# Magento 2. Sample of admin module form

Tags: forms, admin-panel, magento-2.0

Anybody have a very simple sample(with minimum code) of magento's admin module with form, that can add/edit/delete some stuff?

Cause i have some problems while using existing code, included in engine or from int's solutions.

Comment: here is an example : https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-sample-module/tree/master/SR/Weblog

Comment: Please  past ur code?

Comment: It's too dangerous. There are a lot of problems.

Comment: Have a look at the Magento 2 samples. Maybe you find there what you need? https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples